# How to solve MediaPlayer Error "Can't play this video"

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-mediaplayer

### I had a problem with my videoview.

When I try play video from specific URL at my API-27 emulator Android show me message dialog

> Can't play this video

That's it what I get in Logcat

> source returned error -1010, 0 retries left
>
> initFromDataSource, source has no track!
>
> Failed to init from data source!
>
> MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -2147483648)
>
> MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)

---

**That's my code where I use my videoview**

```
mVideoView = findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        mMediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mVideoView.setVideoPath("https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4");
        mVideoView.requestFocus();
        initListeners();
```

**initListeners method**

```
mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mVideoView.setMediaController(mMediaController);
                mVideoView.setBackground(null);
                mMediaController.setAnchorView(mVideoView);
                mMediaController.show();
                mVideoView.start();
            }
        });
        mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
mVideoView.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.webinar_photo_preview));
            }
        });
```

I test my videoview feature at api23, api24 and everything sounds good.
Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**EDITED:** Now I found that the error also appears on api24

Comment: `at api23, api24` was it on emulators as well?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko yes, by api23, api24 I meant emulators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was in VideoView, setVideoPath set videos only with little file size (1 - 2 MB) and if it size is bigger MediaPlayer crashes with `MEDIA_ERROR_SYSTEM (-2147483648)` - (low-level system error), [read in documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener.html) . That why I start using exoPlayer.

Answer (score 0):

Its look like your code is working fine and maybe the problem is that you are not using cookies that are send to browser at the time of request.

> In simple terms this video is not for direct access via code.

If you still wants to try the steps below.

1. Make http request to link (https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4) and store the received cookies.
2. Use the received cookies with your next request when you want to play the video.

> **Note** - If you want to use cookies to play video it can be done via ExoPlayer(https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer).

Comment: Hmm... I think not.

Comment: Problem was with cashing of video not with cookies.

Comment: Glad to hear that but i have used media player with large (100mb) files too.